# Gradle: invalid symbol: 'new'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to run my program after doing some things in the SDK Manager and get the following error:

> Gradle: invalid symbol: 'new'

and

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':MijnCijfers:processDebugResources'.

I didn't change anything in my code, but all lines who reffers to "R" gives a error. For developing I use Android Studio 0.2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if your R.java file is generated. If not, you probably have an error in your xml file.

Comment: In my case I made a custom attribute in values/attrs.xml which had a value (enum) named "default"... Appears that you cannot use reserved keywords here as well.